# Unrealistic behavior with the rigid body physics

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm facing an issue with potato physics in Blender as [demonstrated in this video](https://youtube.com/shorts/odQfgokXTrU?feature=share), and I hope someone can help me understand what's going wrong. The potatoes seem to bounce in an unrealistic manner when they come into contact with each other.

Potato mass: 1 kg
Rigid body shape: Mesh
Gravity setting: 0.7 (I reduced it to avoid aggressive falling, but even when set to 1, the potato still bounces)
Bounciness: 0
Friction: 0
Rigid body world speed: 0.6

Any insights or suggestions on how I can make the interaction more realistic?

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Without your file to test exactly what is happening there, I can only give the advice that having a friction of 0 is very unrealistic. Potatoes have rough surfaces, so I would rather set the friction to something high like 0.8 or 0.9, at least with my short test this looked better. And probably it is okay to use _Convex Hull_ as _Collision Shape_, since the potatoes probably do not have much holes to be considered in the simulation, because _Convex Hull_ will be calculated faster than _Mesh_.

Comment: maybe you wanna try a soft body simulation? which potatoes actually are - rigid bodies are stones, metal and these kind of things.

Comment: @Chris On this small scale rigid body physics are good enough, if you do not want closeups in slow motion of the the small deformations a potato gets... at least if it's not months old an has a consistency of somewhere between soft rubber ball and potato mash :D Simulating this with soft bodies would be overkill, I guess. How much "wobbling" do you see on potatoes thrown in a bowl that would justify a soft body simulation? And with the incorrect settings they could bounce around just as much unnaturally as they are doing now with the rigid body simulation.